# Confusion in limits with trigonometric functions

Tags: limits, trigonometry

Evaluate $$L=\lim_{r\to0} \frac{r\cos r}{r\cos r + \sin r}$$

In the solution it is written that as $r\to0$, $\sin r = r$ and $\cos r = 1$. Hence, we replace the trigonometric functions with $r$ and $1$ so that we can evaluate the limit easily. Therefore,

$L=\lim_{r\to0} \frac{r\cdot1}{r\cdot1 + r}=\frac{1}{2}$.

Now, consider the limit $G =\lim_{r\to0} (\frac{1}{r^{2}}-\frac{1}{\sin^{2}r})$. If we apply the above logic to this question, we will get $G=0$, which is wrong.

So why is the same logic not applicable in the second case?

Comment: Nice question! What your example actually proves is that the solution that you were given is not correct. It reaches the right answer with a faulty argument.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I see. So basically we cannot replace functions inside the limit this way, right? I suppose taking $r$ outside and canceling is the best way to solve the 1st limit.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the reasoning of the given solution (poor notations set aside, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form#Equivalent_infinitesimal)). The reason why it does not apply to your example is that you cannot substract (or add) equivalents because of their definition.

Comment: I would do\begin{align}\lim_{r\to0}\frac{r\cos r}{r\cos r+\sin r}&=\lim_{r\to0}\frac{\cos r}{\cos r+\frac{\sin r}r}\\&=\frac{\lim_{r\to0}\cos r}{\lim_{r\to0}\cos r+\frac{\sin r}r}\\&=\frac1{1+1}\\&=\frac12.\end{align}

Comment: Using that $\sin r /r \to 1$ as $r \to 0$ is basically the same argument behind the one given in the solution. @JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: @nicomezi Why are subtraction and addition of equivalents not valid but multiplication and division are fine?

Comment: @nicomezi That's an interpretation of the given solution. A more literal interpretation would be to take the expression $\frac{r\cos r}{r\cos r+\sin r}$ and to replace $\cos r$ and $\sin r$ with $1$ and $r$ respectively, which is the interpretation given by the OP. In my opinion, the given solution is sloppy, at best.

Comment: It is sloppy. But the argument itself is not faulty in my opinion. @JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: @Curiouserandcuriouser Because $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ are said equivalent at $a$ if $\lim f(x)/g(x) \to 1$ as $x \to a$. Assume $f_1,f_2$ are equivalent to $g_1,g_2$, we have that $\underset{x \to a }\lim f_1 / f_2 = \underset{x \to a }\lim f_1 g_1 g_2 / (f_2 g_1 g_2)  =  \underset{x \to a }\lim g_1 / g_2 $. If one rather evaluates $\underset{x \to a } \lim f_1 + f_2$, you might have problem with indeterminate forms as in the example you gave (but it will work if all limits are finite).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos No. The solution of book is correct while of OP is wrong. See my answer I have explained.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the idea is that close enough to $0$, $\sin(r)=r+o(r)$, where $\frac{o(r)}{r}\to 0$ when $r\to 0$ (this is apparent if you calculate the Taylor expansion of $\sin r$). So if we replace $\sin(r)$ with $r+o(r)$ we see that: $$\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{r\cos(r)}{r\cos(r)+r+o(r)}=\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{r\cos(r)}{r(\cos(r)+1+\frac{o(r)}{r})}=\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{\cos(r)}{\cos(r)+1+\frac{o(r)}{r}}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Their argument is not as much "faulty" as it is not formal, because obviously $\sin r$ is not $r$ when $r\to 0$, it's just that $\sin(r)-r$ is $o(r)$, meaning that when taking limits their "contribution" to the limit is the same. They way I calculated the limit puts this in a more formal manner, and it is a routine way to solve limits of this kind.

Another reason they may have wrote that as $r\to 0$, $\sin r=r$ is because $\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{sin(r)}{r}=1$. Either way, it is not a formal argument. If one wants to solve the limit using this argument, it will look like this: $$\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{r\cos(r)}{r\cos(r)+\sin r}=\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{r\cos(r)}{r(\cos(r)+\frac{\sin r}{r})}=\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{\cos(r)}{(\cos(r)+\frac{\sin r}{r})}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: I agree with this answer and would like to add that a correct notation woud be $\sin r \underset{r \to 0}\sim r$.

Answer (score 2):

Let me show you more clearly and precisely that what are you doing in the second case. You are basically doing this :

$\lim_{r\to 0}( \frac{1}{r^2} - \frac{1}{\sin^2r}) $ = $\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{1}{r^2} -$ $\lim_{r\to0}\frac{1}{\sin^2r}$

Since ${\sin r\to r}$ as $r\to 0$ , hence

$$\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{1}{r^2} -\lim_{r\to0}\frac{1}{\sin^2r}=\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{1}{r^2} -\lim_{r\to0}\frac{1}{r^2}$$

Again ,

$$\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{1}{r^2} -\lim_{r\to0}\frac{1}{r^2} = 
\lim_{r\to 0}(\frac{1}{r^2} -\frac{1}{r^2}) = 0$$

You did **distribution and re-association** of limits which is wrong.

Book author did **only distribution** and **NO re-association** of limits which is correct.

This is a very common mistake while studying limits for the first time. Hence, the book solution is correct as he reached the final answer in one step after distribution; while you did more than one step after distribution.

Comment: I don't agree that that's what the OP did. Instead, it was simply$$\lim_{r\to0}\left(\frac1{r^2}-\frac1{\sin^2r}\right)=\lim_{r\to0}\left(\frac1{r^2}-\frac1{r^2}\right)=0.$$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos    The OP's step from the LHS to RHS is the thing that I have explained more clearly in starting of my answer . It is not possible to change $\sin r$ to $r$ without knowing that the limit goes to zero. This is what I have done in the starting of my answer .

Comment: The OP has used the fact(knowledge) that $r$ goes to zero. And in mathematical terms, it is same as distributing limits in this case.